# imacros javascript loop based on extracted value

Tags: javascript, imacros

This loop calls macroWait even if the return value extracttext does not match- what am I doing wrong?
If the text is found I want the macro to pause via the macrowait timeout function to allow a video on that page to download.
Then it should go to the next iteration and look for the Analysis text as before.
If this text is not found, it will wait the default time.

```
var macro;
macro =  "CODE:";
macro +=  "VERSION BUILD=9052613" + "\n"; 
macro +="SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 25"+"\n";
macro +=  "URL GOTO=theURL=" + "{{theDate}}" + "&no=" + "{{theNumber}}" + "&lang=eng"+ "\n";
macro +="TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:<SP>Analysis EXTRACT=href"+"\n";

var macroWait;

macroWait ="CODE:";
macroWait +="WAIT SECONDS=600"; 
var iret;
var extracttext;    
var maxLoop=10;
var doesContain;
var theNumber =1;

for(var i=0;i<maxLoop;i++)
{
var curr = new Date(2014,0,1);
curr.setDate(curr.getDate()+i)
var theDate = curr.yyyymmdd();
iimSet("theDate", theDate);
iimSet("theNumber",n(theNumber)); 
iret = iimPlay(macro);
extracttext = iimGetExtract();
doesContain = extracttext.contains("passthrough");
//cannot find video then do not add timeout

if(doesContain == true)
{

iimPlay(macroWait)

}
else { next;}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If 'doesContain' gets boolean value true or false, then '(doesContain > -1)' is true in any case.